# Change class and text in html because of php result

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my html i want to call a php script (which calls a python script and check if my nas is online or offline - this works fine) and returns me either "online" or "offline". Depending on the result the class ("label label-success" to "label label-danger") and text ("Online" to "Offline") of my online/offline-indicator should change. 
How do i make this happen?

HTML

```
<span class="label label-success">Online</span>
```

PHP

```
<?php
  $result = popen("pingnas.py", "r");
  return $result;
?>
```

Comment: Set the content of your span using javascript.In which your $result will decide what should be your content.Use removeclass and add.class().

Answer (score 1):

You can make an AJAX call to the php script which in turn calls the python script to check whether the user is online or offline.

Something like this.

```
-In your Javascript, make an AJAX call to PHP script.
-PHP in turn executes python to see if the user is online or offline.
-Send the JSON response. May be something like {"status":"online"}
-Based on the JSON response, change the HTML of the span element.
```

Comment: Okay, i know how to code 1-3 but how do i change the html of the span element based on the result?

Comment: If the AJAX request is success, then

var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
document.getElementById("indicator").innerHTML = response.status;

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to the span that you want to manipulate

```
<span class="label label-success" id="indicator">Online</span>
```

Return the result variable to javascript and then manipulate the text/classname with javascript. Assuming that the python script returns 1 for success and 0 for failure

```
<?php
    $result = popen("pingnas.py", "r");
?>

<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    var setStatus = function(status) {
    var ind = document.getElementById('indicator');

    if (status === 1) {
       ind.innerHTML='Online';
       ind.className='label label-success';

       return;
    }

    ind.innerHTML='Offline';
    ind.className='label label-fail';
}

window.onload = function() {
    setStatus(<?php echo $result ?>);
};
</script>

...rest of the HTML
```

Comment: Nothing happens when i use this code. To test the code i do <?php $result =0; ?> but nothing happend.

Comment: Is the id of the element set correctly? try console.log(ind);

Comment: Firebug shows me an error so i do "var ind=document.getElementById" and the error is gone. One thing i'm not sure about is that you wrote "if(status*1)" shouldn't it be "if(status==1)"? Anyway, none of them works for me.